# Estimate number in an interval, given mean and standard deviation of normal distribution

Tags: statistics

The weekly wages of 1000 workers are normally distributed around a mean of Rs. 70 and a standard deviation of Rs. 5. Estimate the number of workers whose weekly wages will be:
a. Between 70 and 72
b. Between 69 and 72
c. More than 75
d. Less than 63

Comment: Not exactly a polite way to start a question...

Comment: Hint: For D, $P(W < 63) = P(Z < \frac{63-70}{5}) = P(Z<-1.4) = 0.0808$, where W is the wage random variable, and Z the standard normal random variable.

Comment: You should tell us what you have tried and where you got stuck. It will help us to help you!

Comment: I stuck here(b) P(69<X<72) = P(69-70/5 < X-70/5 < 72-70/5)
                          = P (-0.2 < Z < 0.4)
P(69<X<72) =  Area from -0.2 to 0.4
           = (Area from -0.2 to 0) + (Area from 0 to 0.4)
           = (Area from 0 to 0.2) + (Area from 0 to 0.4)
           =

Comment: And stuck here P(X>75) = P( X-70/5 < 75 - 70/5)
                       = P( Z < 1)
P(Z < 1) = Area from 1 to ∞
         = (Area from 0 to ∞ ) - (Area from 0 to 1)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to solve the problem as below,
Solution:
Given, N= 1000,      μ= 70,      σ= 5
    Therefore, Z= (X-μ)/σ  =(X-70)/5, is a standard normal variate
    Probability of workers whose wages are between 70 & 72
P (7075) = P((X-70)/5>(75-70)/5)= P(z>1)
P(z>1)= area from 1to ∞ = [area from 0 to ∞] - [area from 0 to 1]
              = 0.5-0.3413= 0.1591.
Therefore from 1000 workers no of workers whose weekly wages are more than Rs. 75=  N x P (Z>1) = 1000*0.1591= 159 Nos
    Probability of workers whose wages are less than 63
P (X<63) = P((X-70)/5<(63-70)/5)= P(z<-1.4)
P(z<-1.4)=area from-∞ to -1.4 = [area from 0 to ∞] -[area from 0 to 1.4]
              = 0.5-0.4192= 0.0808
Therefore from 1000 workers no of workers whose weekly wages are less than Rs. 63=  N x P (Z<1.4) = 1000*0.0808= 81 Nos